# Can we measure data Transfer rate in each Android Device connected thorught hotpsot

Tags: android, wifimanager, hotspot

is there a way by which we get data speed from each Device Connected through Hotspot

Comment: Make/model of hotspot? Looked in the manual? Not sure what feature(s) might be the one you need? Put that in the question. The answer is 'sometimes' and you may need to use something between the hotspot and devices; but nobody here can see your config.

Comment: Please explain more of what you're asking and show what you've tried